# GraphQL Query List compare two lists

Tags: graphql

I would like to modify the below GraphQl query to accept a list of tags and return all elements that end with the tag.

```
query AllElementsQuery($Tag: String) {
  AllElements(filter: { Attribute: {Name: {eq: "Tag"}, Value: {endsWith: $Tag }} }) {
    Element { Name, Type}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get an answer from someone within my company, it seems that I can compare two lists in GraphQL but not using endsWith:

```
query AllElementsQuery($Tag: [String]) {
AllElements(filter: { Attribute: {Name: {eq: "Tag"}, Value: {in: $Tag }} }) {
  Element { Name, Type}
}}
```